# set up sharing rules in a way that allows Community Users to edit their own Contact record

Tags: community, userrecordaccess

I need some help. Can you tell me please how can I set up sharing rules in a way that allows Community Users to edit their own Contact record ?

I tried to change OWD, Sharing rules, Sharing on community settings. I see the record but I can't edit it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use the standard community profile page to let user update their user record. You can then have a trigger/process builder in the backend that copies the values from the contact to the related user. In this way, you can also keep the two records in sync as they are related.